# animateLayoutChanges animates elements separately even though they're in a ViewGroup

Tags: java, android, animation

I want to animate a ViewGroup (LinearLayout) from GONE to VISIBLE. The ViewGroup contains two elements and they get animated separately. Is it possible to "group" them in such a way that the animation considers them as one element?

Answer (score 0):

Give your LinearLayout an id and add `android:visibility="invisible"`. Then initialize it as an object in your class :

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_id);
```

and then simply use `ll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

Comment: If a View is `invisible` it'll still take space in the layout. Currently I'm basically doing the same just with `android:visibility="gone"`.